# Registry Key not set on client as in GPO specified (added zeroes)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I observed a really strange behaviour and hoped one of you could help me.
I created a GP-object on a Server 2012 R2 Domain Controller, which should set some registry entries on clients (used to define the default font in outlook). The keys are all "REG_BINARY" - hex strings.

When I define the value like this in the GPO: 
3C 68 74 6D 6C 3E 0D [...] (not pasting the whole, huge string here ;))

What the client (Windows 10 x64) has set after gpupdate:
3C 06 80 74 06 D0 6C 03 E0 0D 00

Where do those addition zeroes come from? What am I doing wrong?

Regards, Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the zeros are being added where there are spaces in the string you pasted. Try removing all whitespace characters from your source string before pasting into the policy.